# Hey a beginner here

Tags: android, android-studio

how can i match an iteration variable to the input variable in edit text, i wanted to create the armstrong number

it goes like this

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Integer one = Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString());
             Integer two = Integer.parseInt(edt2.getText().toString());
             Integer three = Integer.parseInt(edt3.getText().toString());

             Integer num1 = (one * one * one);
             Integer num2 = (two * two * two);
             Integer num3 = (three * three * three);
             Integer sum = (num1 + num2 + num3);
             tv2.setText(sum);

             for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                 if (i==1){
                     (1 == 153)
                 }
             }

         }
     });
```

Comment: i didn't finished the looping as i don't know what to put

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button check;
    private TextView result;
    private EditText input_number;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        check =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_check);
        check.setOnClickListener(this);
        result =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        input_number =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_number);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int num = Integer.parseInt(input_number.getText().toString());
        int n = num;
        int check =0,remainder;

        while(num>0){
            remainder = num % 10;
            check = (int) (check + Math.pow(remainder,3));
            num = num/10;
        }
        if(check == n)
            result.setText(n+"is an Armstrong Number");
        else
        result.setText(n+"is not an Armstrong Number");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: all what i did is an analogy with java;

check on here : https://www.javatpoint.com/armstrong-number-in-java#:~:text=Armstrong%20Number%20in%20Java%3A%20A,153%20is%20an%20Armstrong%20number.

Armstrong Number in Java: A positive number is called armstrong number if it is equal to the sum of cubes of its digits for example 0, 1, 153, 370, 371, 407 etc.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm if user input is an armstrong number, you don't need to iterate. You simply need to compute sum of the cube of individual digits and confirm if it arithmetically equals the value of the figure of the digits when combine.

Your code will thus be refactored like below to solve the problem

```
     btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Integer one = Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString());
               Integer two = Integer.parseInt(edt2.getText().toString());
               Integer three = Integer.parseInt(edt3.getText().toString());
               // convert input text to three fields to one String
               String joinedText = "" + one + two + three;

               Integer num1 = (one * one * one);
               Integer num2 = (two * two * two);
               Integer num3 = (three * three * three);
               Integer sum = (num1 + num2 + num3);
               // you must setText as String
               tv2.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
               if(sum == Integer.parseInt(joinedText)){
                   // This is an armstrong number
               }else {
                   // This is not an armstrong number
               }

     }
 });
```